# Using Facebook Async Display Kit in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview, swift, asynchronous

I want to use facebook async display kit in my project for smooth loading in tableview. I read them GitHub page but it's not clear for me. Can anyone help me to understand it?

> (ASDK can also be used as a regular static library: Copy the project to your codebase manually, adding AsyncDisplayKit.xcodeproj to your workspace. Add libAsyncDisplayKit.a, AssetsLibrary, and Photos to the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase. Include -lc++ -ObjC in your project linker flags.)

I did copy xcodeproj file into my own project and add -ObjC. But I do not know what they means by `Add libAsyncDisplayKit.a, AssetsLibrary, and Photos to the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase.`. I did not find such files.

Please, do not minus my question, I'm new in Swift. Just show me the road. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that you have to add the libraries you mention in the "link binary with libraries" row of the Build Phases section.

You can arrive to that section by: 
- clicking in the project file in the project navigator view 
- clicking in the target of the project where you want to use the library in the targets column
- clicking in the Build Phases section you will see the Link Binary With Libraries row.

Just click on the + button and add libAsyncDisplayKit.a, Photos.framework and the AssetsLibrary.framework.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way of adding external libs is to use cocoa pods as employeed [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86365/asyncdisplaykit-tutorial-achieving-60-fps-scrolling). (A collectionsview implementation a tableView should be somewhat similar)

(I am not the writer of that article)